# Получить данные из базы в виде CSV строки. Это возможно?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Пусть есть таблица:

```
id |  number
------------
1  |  123
2  |  12324
3  |  4542
4  |  52452
....
```

Хочу сделать селект, чтобы база вернула строку:

```
"123,12324,4542,52452"
```

Это возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно. Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](http://vexell.ru/2010/10/mysql-implode-explode/) - http://vexell.ru/2010/10/mysql-implode-explode/ .

Comment: SET group_concat_max_len = 4096; # Нужное значение

Comment: а как прописать такую штуку в майскл?

Comment: Надо просто выполнить этот запрос при соединении с БД. В php это выглядит как mysql_query('SET group_concat_max_len = 4096;');

Comment: перезапускать майскл нужно? у меня как было 1024 так и остаётся( и как проверить что параметр изменился?

Comment: решение найдено!

Comment: SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 10000;